# How do I get a value after pipe complete?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-pipe

For example.
I want Angular auto update the value (using observable).

```
// in test.component.ts
ngOnInit(){
  let i = 0;
  this.test = new Observalble<any>((ob) => {
    setInterVal(() => {
      ob.next({
        i: i++,
      })
    },1000);
  });
}

<!-- in test.component.html -->
<p>{{ (test | async).i }}</p> <!-- not work -->
<p>{{ (test.i | async) }}</p> <!-- not work -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to fix your spelling errors first: `setInterVal` should be `setInterval` (lower case v), and `Observalble` should be `Observable`.

Then, you need to add the null safe operator, as the async result of `test` will start out undefined, and cause errors if you try get the `i` property from an undefined value. By adding the `?`, it will only try to read `i` if `test | async` is not null.

```
// in test.component.ts
ngOnInit(){
  let i = 0;
  this.test = new Observable<any>((ob) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      ob.next({
        i: i++,
      })
    },1000);
  });
}

<!-- in test.component.html -->
<p>{{ (test | async)?.i }}</p> <!-- not work -->
```

[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dmxtx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)